# What is the meaning of opts=${1:+--host $1} in bash?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion, positional-parameter

In a bash script, I stumbled upon this piece of code:

```sh
opts=${1:+--host $1}
/path/somecmd $opts somesubcmd
```

By testing, I found out that `$opts` expands to `--host $1` whatever `$1` is.
I wonder what is the purpose of this syntax.
Why not simply use `opts="--host $1"` ?

Is it a specific way to pass options to a command ?

Comment: [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is a good reference about what all those `${...}` do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [bash manual says](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:+word}`
>
> If *parameter* is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of *word* is substituted.

When the bash manual says "parameter", it means "variable". When it says "null", it means "the empty string".

In other words, `${foo:+bar}` works like `bar`, but only if `$foo` is not empty.

In your case,

```
${1:+--host $1}
```

it checks `$1`. If `$1` is unset or empty, the whole construct expands to nothing.

Otherwise it expands to `--host $1`, as you have observed.

Answer (score 0):

It prepends `--host` to the first parameter due to the `+`, but only if `$1` isn't empty.

```
$ function mytest { echo ${1:+--host $1}; }
$ mytest ls
--host ls
$ mytest ""
```

Equivalent would be:

```
$ function mytest { [ -z "$1"] || echo --host $1; }
$ mytest ls
--host ls
```

There's a lot to read about [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Answer (score 0):

The parameter expansion `${variable:+value}` produces `value` if `variable` is nonempty, and nothing otherwise. So this is a way to say "add `--host $1` if `$1` is set." (The expansion should properly quote the string; `${1:+--host "$1~}`)